# How can I make it so my method can have the same capabilities as View::make() so that I may make use of ->with() which is in the View class?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning Laravel and there are some things that aren't clear to me.

I've added a method to the BaseController class which will be taking care of my ajax requests.

```
public function ajaxView($page) {
    $view = View::make($page);

    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $sections = $view->renderSections(); // returns an associative array of 'content', 'head' and 'footer'
        return $sections['content']; // this will only return whats in the content section
    }

    return $view; // just a regular request so return the whole view
}
```

I have a ProfileController which extends BaseController and I have the following code:

```
return View::make('profile.user')
    ->with('user', $user);
```

I would like to change it to:

```
return parent::ajaxView('profile.user')
    ->with('user', $user);
```

How can I make it so my ajaxView method has the same capabilities as View::make() so that I can make use of ->with()? Is there a way to extend it some how even though ajaxView is a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `with`, you can pass the data in as an array:

```
public function ajaxView($page, $data = [])
{
    $view = View::make($page, $data);

    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $sections = $view->renderSections();

        return $sections['content'];
    }

    return $view;
}
```

Then in your `ProfileController` pass in your data:

```
return $this->ajaxView('profile.user', ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: Where is the View::make() method located so that I can check it out? It doesn't seem to be in View.php.